# Which Bluetooth profile I should use on a client side for tethering?

Tags: android, bluetooth, tethering

Which Bluetooth profile I should use on a client-side for tethering?
For example, I enabled tethering on my Android device and want to use Internet on other specific device, that doesn't have native support of tethering.
I know there are different Bluetooth profiles, is it possible to use some of them (PAN for example) for this purpose?

Thanks!